# How to save a PDF file from WebView in iBooks or an other PDF readable app?

Tags: ios, pdf, ibooks

I have an Xcode (iPhone) app with a WebView. My homepage in this WebView contains a PDF file. I can open this PDF file. But I cannot save it.

In normal Safari browser there are the buttons "Open in…" and "Open in "iBooks"". But in my WebView I can just open the PDF file. I'm not able to save/open to/in iBooks or any other app. Why that? Can somebody help me please? Thanks for every answer.

Comment: From where are you opening pdf file in webview?

Comment: I'm opening it directly from the internet, not from local directory. Can you help me please?

Comment: Because your using a custom UIWebView you have to create the actions it includes. For downloading it's easy. Create a directory and then save your file to it. The to open in whatever applications are installed on the device you use `UIDocumentInteractionController`   There are numerous tutorials on the web. Do some research first

Answer (score 0):

You can download pdf file in form of NSData and save it in document directory.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"deu-net.com/Berlin-Buch/14Buch.pdf"];
NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Get path directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Create PDF_Documents directory
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"**PUT FILENAME YOU WANT**"];

[dataPdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Where do I have to set it. In ViewController.m?

Comment: Yes. Depending on your requirements, you can put this code in viewDidLoad or IBAction of a button.

Comment: I copied this code under "- (void)viewDidLoad {" in ViewController.m, right?

Comment: Yes right, if you want to save file as soon as the view loads.

Comment: I get two errors:
NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url];

Use of undeclared identifier 'pdfOnline'


[[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

Expected ':'


What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: I have updated the code. In place of "YouURL " you have to put the url from which the pdf file is downloading.

Comment: @FawadMasud you should include the dispatch syntax for downloading in the background thread.

Comment: NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:deu-net.com/Berlin-Buch/14Buch.pdf];

Invalid digit 'B' in dezimal constant
Use undeclared identifier 'Buch'
Use undeclared identifier 'Berlin'
Use undeclared identifier 'deu'
Use undeclared identifier 'net'

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There is no error now. But there is still a question: How does it work now? When I open the PDF file (deu-net.com/Berlin-Buch/14Buch.pdf) in my WebView it still doesn‘t ask for "Save in…". Why that? What am I doing wrong? Some idea?

Comment: It will not ask automatically. You have to do it yourself. create a button and put the code inside its action.

Comment: Can I create this code on my website? Or just in my app?